# The update.php doesn't want to run it's complete course

Tags: 7, database, updating

I updated core Drupal (D7.14) and all seems to running perfectly. Only some updates for the database are required. So I run the update.php and I get through the first stages and I can see the pending updates when I am on the Review updates page. But when I continue (press the button). It seems to get stuck. I don't get to next screen, it just keeps on loading. In one browser I get a blank screen but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too. One update took a lot of memory on my shared host. I tried it several times during the Day until I got Lucky.  Maybe a glance in the Apache log Files will help?

Comment: Thanks! That might be just it... In that case I hope I have a lucky day too soon!

Comment: It worked. Seems like it was my lucky day after all! The update.php script went all the way through to the last step and all is well...

Comment: Great! If you mark my Answer as useful (uparrow) and check it as solved (checkmark) I will be thrilled, too.

Comment: You might want to look into Drush, you can do updates there but it's much less of a memory hog. Chances are you don't have enough memory allocated to what Drupal actually needs to work efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multi-sites running off one installation, make sure you are running the update.php on the original site, as this same behaviour seems to happen if you are trying to run the script from one of the other sites.